# A call to Bind was not well formatted

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've recently upgraded to VS2013. For some reason I'm getting the above error when trying to bind data in a detailsview. This is my code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Resource Link">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="RESOURCE_LINK" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Resource Link") %>'
            TextMode="MultiLine" class="myTextEditor" cols="50" name="tinymce" Height='300px'
            Width='600px'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
    <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**(Also tried "[Resource Link]")**

The same code works fine on past asp applications I've published. What I'm asking:

1. Why does this error appear on vs2013 and not vs2010?
2. How can I change that code to allow the bind?

I've read several articles including Eilon Liptons blog post on Databinding but I don't see a solution.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does really the property which you want to bind have an space on its name????

Comment: It certainly does....

Comment: And how in the world did you created a property in a class with spaces on its name??? I'm very curious about it :D

Comment: I didn't. Binding from sql server db

Comment: Try "<%#Bind('Resource Link') %>", just a guess

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?

Comment: Someone voted it as offtopic...

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use Eval instead of Bind

```
Text='<%# Eval("Resource Link") %>'
```

Comment: `Eval` is one way binding.